# BeautifulSoup: Extract links to file and append new links only on subsequent rerun

Tags: python, python-2.7, hyperlink, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have the code below to extract links from specific sites.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, sys
import re

def jobsinghana():
    site = "http://www.jobsinghana.com/jobs"
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    mayday = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(mayday)
    jobs = soup.find_all('a', {'class' : 'hover'})
    print str(jobs).strip('[]')


def modernghana():
    site = "http://www.modernghana.com/GhanaHome/classifieds/list_classifieds.asp?    menu_id=7&sub_menu_id=362&gender=&cat_id=173&has_price=2"
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    jobpass = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(jobpass)
    jobs = soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('show_classifieds'))
    for a in jobs:
        header = a.parent.find_previous_sibling('h3').text
        a.string = header
        print a

jobsinghana = jobsinghana()
modernghana = modernghana()


alllinks = open('content.html', 'w')
alllinks.write("\n".join((jobsinghana, modernghana)))
allinks.close()
```

1. The last 3 lines is suppose to write the extracted links to file but I'm getting the error below:

   ```
   TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
   ```
2. I also notice that the code extracts all the links all over again anytime I run the program but because most of those links would have been extracted at an earlier instance of the code run, I'm interested in extracting and appending only the new links to the file upon subsequent run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your functions *returns* anything. The default then is to return `None`, resulting in your error.

Add `return` statements to your functions instead of printing the results. You are gathering lists of links, so you'll need to alter your code to return the lists and concatenate the two lists, or write them to the output file separately:

```
def jobsinghana():
    site = "http://www.jobsinghana.com/jobs"
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    mayday = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(mayday)
    return map(str, soup.find_all('a', {'class' : 'hover'}))


def modernghana():
    site = "http://www.modernghana.com/GhanaHome/classifieds/list_classifieds.asp?    menu_id=7&sub_menu_id=362&gender=&cat_id=173&has_price=2"
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    jobpass = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(jobpass)
    jobs = soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('show_classifieds'))
    result = []
    for a in jobs:
        header = a.parent.find_previous_sibling('h3').text
        a.string = header
        result.append(str(a))
    return result

jobsinghana_links = jobsinghana()
modernghana_links = modernghana()


with open('content.html', 'w') as alllinks:
    alllinks.write("\n".join(jobsinghana_links + modernghana_links))
```

If you need to skip links you found before, you'll have to read in the links, preferably into a set, to test against when scanning again:

```
def read_existing():
    with open('content.html') as alllinks:
        return {line.strip() for line in alllinks}

existing = read_existing()
jobsinghana_links = jobsinghana(existing)
modernghana_links = modernghana(existing)
```

and in the two functions reading links, filter out any link already present in `existing`, using `if link in existing:` tests.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, but I made the changes you suggested and now I'm getting the error as `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Tag found`

Comment: Right, adjusted `jobsinghana()` to return strings too. Are you certain you want to write `<a href>` tags here and not the URLs themselves, btw?

Comment: I think I want the `<a href>` tags as well because I want them to display automatically as a link for a single page Django app I'm putting together. It's actually my first dabble into programming though so I may be wrong but I want to get the whole concept working in Python before I move on to putting it together as a Django app. Thanks

Comment: It'd be easier to test pre-existing links if you stored *just* the URL. I'd not copy across the whole tag into my own Django site; this would give a scraped site a way into displaying things in your site you would not want there. You can always generate the `<a href="...">` part yourself in your Django template.

Comment: Wow! thanks,I think I will  go that way when I start working on the Django app